# Post request with ajax for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have writtent this script to send notification from my HTML page.
When i try to send the request, i get both messages `"Success"` and `"Fail"` and the notification is not sent. I call the function `get_data_for_notification()` on button click.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_data_for_notification(){
        var title = document.getElementById('news_title').value;
        var subtitle = document.getElementById('news_small_description').value;

        $.ajax({
                 type : 'POST',
                 url : "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                 headers : {
                     Authorization : 'key=mykey'
                 },
                 contentType : 'application/json',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: JSON.stringify({"to": "/topics/android",  "priority" : "high", "notification": {"title":title,"body":subtitle}}),
                 success : alert("Success")            ,
                 error : alert("Fail")
             }) ;
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the button type, i needed to use `type="button"` and not `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script executes, *before* sending the request, `alert("Success")` and `alert("Fail")` and assigns their return value as the event handlers.

You have to wrap them in an anonymous function:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'key=mykey'
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "to": "/topics/android",
            "priority": "high",
            "notification": {
                "title": title,
                "body": subtitle
            }
        }),
        success: function(responseData) {
            alert("Success");
        }
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            /*alert("Fail");*/   // alerting "Fail" isn't useful in case of an error...
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check the request and response in the network tab of your developer tools, check the documentation on how to make a valid request, ...

Comment: Sorry it was a typo... but now i only get an alert `Status: Error, Error`.